# jquery - Can I count input name first slot of array 2 dimension?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want to count the first `[]`  of input name

```
<input type="text" name="Hello[a][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[a][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[a][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[b][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[b][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[c][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[c][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[c][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[c][]">
```

the result of count should be **3**   (a, b ,c) 
How could I do with jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the input elements and use an object for referring repetition, when new name occurred increment a counter.

```js
var ref = {},
  count = 0;

$('input').each(function() {
  if (!(this.name in ref)) {
    ref[this.name] = true;
    count++
  }
})

console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Hello[a][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[a][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[a][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[b][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[b][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[c][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[c][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[c][]">
<input type="text" name="Hello[c][]">
```